# C# XNA How to make sprite disappear?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, sprite

The title says it all. I simply want a sprite to disappear in a certain point in the game. For some reason I can't find the answer to that anywhere as simple as it sounds.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop rendering it in the `Draw` method.

Perhaps add an `if` block around the code for drawing the sprite, and you can choose when to draw it and when not to.